# Can either mean both in this context?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading about [the Edwards v Canada (AG) case on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_v_Canada_(AG)), and in the petition put forward by her and the other famous five to the federal government I read the following sentence:

> I. Is power vested in the Governor-General in Council of Canada, or the Parliament of Canada, or either of them, to appoint a female to the Senate of Canada?

My question is this; does the clause *"or either of them"* contribute anything to the sentence?

I was wondering if it might be meaning "both" in this instance, but at least according to [this site](https://jakubmarian.com/both-vs-either-in-english/), which was one of the top results on Google when trying to find out if that is a valid use, *"it means (...) one or the other, but not both of them simultaneously"*

Answer (score 2):

I think it asks whether one of the following is true:

1. The Governor-General can appoint a female (but the Parliament can't), or
2. The Parliament can appoint a female (but the Governor-General can't), or
3. Either the Governor-General or the Parliament can appoint a female.

In this context, saying that either A or B can do the thing is the same as saying that both A and B can do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sentence should have an "either", but not tacked on at the end.

I. Is power vested in **either** the Governor-General in Council of Canada, or the Parliament of Canada, to appoint a female to the Senate of Canada?

In a sentence with an "or" that means "either/or", it might make sense to add at the end "or both of them", but "or either of them" doesn't make sense.